# INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger not firing for views - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, triggers

I have this trigger for a view that populates another table for every insert. The problem is, it doesn't even fire. However, it works amazingly well when applying this same code to a table (and modifying the INSTEAD OF).

The view is `vw_alumnos` and takes data from table `Alumnos`.

For testing purposes, I'm adding rows to `Alumnos`, and they appear correctly in the view.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert_pupils] 
ON [dbo].[vw_Alumnos]   
INSTEAD OF INSERT  
AS    
BEGIN
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RETURN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    declare @table_name varchar(50);  
    declare @id_row varchar(50); 
    declare @change_type varchar(100);  

    set @table_name='vw_Alumnos';  
    set @change_type='addedit';  

    insert into historial_cambios (table_name, id_row, change_type)
        select @table_name, i.EMAIL, @change_type 
        from inserted i
END
```

Answer (score 1):

OK... I found the problem.

This triggers detects when a row is added TO THE VIEW (and not to the table!) so that's why it's not working -> I'm testing by adding rows to the BASE TABLE instead of the VIEW.

Comment: I think you found the cure for the common cold... been searching for this issue all day